# Problems with overriding OnPaint and grabbing mouse events in C# UserControl containing other controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, user-controls

I've made a control which contains few other controls like `PictureBox`, `Label` and `TextBox`. But I'm having two problems:

**1.** I tried to paint some things on top of my control and when I'm overriding `OnPaint`, it results that things I try to draw are under controls that my control contains. Areas on which I would like to draw intersect with controls in ways that are not easy to predict. I mean that it includes something drawn on controls inside as well as on base of control. Is there a simple way to draw something **on top** of all contents of my control? Setting `ForeColor` to Transparent isn't a solution that would help me much.

**2.** I have a problem with grabbing mouse click events when I place my control on a form and add click event handling. It only works when I click on an area not occupied by controls inside. I would like the whole control to react to clicks and other actions like it was one consistent control. How can I redirect/handle these clicks to make them work the way I want?

Thanks in advance for any tips

> **edit:**

Thanks for answer, i hoped for something less complexed.

Finally i decided to do it from scratch, painting all necessary things directly on surface of my `UserControl`, `TextBox` shows up only when it is necessary. That solved all of my problems with drawing and events.

MTH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Overriding a control's `OnPaint` event allows you to draw *onto* that control. Whenever that control is painted, your drawing code will be executed. *Then*, and only then, will the child controls be drawn on top of that control, each of them with their *own* `OnPaint` events executing. Each control is its own window (in the sense of the Windows API), and therefore each is responsible for drawing its own surface. This explains why your graphics are being covered up by the child controls, and why they are only visible in the empty spaces where no child controls have been placed.

The upshot is that drawing on top of multiple controls inside a container is not well-supported. There are a couple of hacks you could try to help get around these limitations, but you may well be disappointed.

The first possible hack is to draw your graphics on the container control as you've already done, and then *also* [draw on top of the child controls themselves](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/GraphicalOverlayComponent.aspx). You'll need to override each child control's `OnPaint` event in order for this to work, however, which immediately presents a problem. A `TextBox` control (along with a `ComboBox`, `ListView`, `TreeView`, and a handful of other controls) doesn't do its drawing in an `OnPaint` event; it's drawn natively by the operating system. The possible workarounds for this are so potentially painful that you might as well forget about it and change your design.

The second possible hack is to add *another* control that sits on top of the container control and do your drawing on its surface. Perhaps the easiest way to do this is by creating something like a transparent panel using the [`WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx) extended window style:

```
public class TransparentPanel : Panel
{
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020;

            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do nothing
    }
}
```

**2)** Again, it becomes relevant that each child control is its own window and handles its own mouse input events. That's why the control whose `MouseClick` event you've overridden is only detecting the clicks that occur *directly* on its surface. The other clicks get passed to the child controls, who just ignore them. Events in WinForms are not bubbled up the control hierarchy.

As before, one possible solution is to handle the `MouseClick` event (and any others you want) for both the container *and* child controls. If you decide to go this route, I think I would recommend consolidating your logic into a single routine and simply calling that routine from each control's event handler.

If you're looking for something more comprehensive, you might check out [Broadcasting Events through a Control Hierarchy](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/event_broadcast.aspx), although I haven't taken the time to read it.

Of course, you could also send the relevant [mouse input messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645601.aspx#_win32_Client_Area_Mouse_Messages) to your parent container control from each child control using the [`SendMessage` API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950.aspx). But I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader because I feel like you asked a simple question expecting a simple answer.

Comment: Well, i must say, i hoped for something more obvious/simpler, in that case i might first try to introduce other plan that at first seemed to me as worst option. I equip my controll with ability to display image and some kind of label on its surface - that way i solve both problems: mouse and painting of additional elements. TextBox will be added/removed dynamicaly if necessary  Anyway thanks for suggestions

Comment: @MoreThanChaos: In general, modifying the appearance of the standard Windows controls is quite difficult. If you really need this type of functionality, you would do well to consider using WPF instead of WinForms. Otherwise, you're right on in adapting your design to the limitations, rather than trying to roll that boulder up a hill. Best of luck!

Comment: (+1) Explanation very good. Also to advise that some controls won't execute the "OnPaint" event handler method, as expected.